# Save multiple google maps points as nested attributes on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, nested-attributes

I have created a scaffold named "Travel", which have as nested attribute "Points".

When I go to the "edit" page of "Travel", I open the js of google maps, and I want to let the users to add as many points as they want.

I don't know how to do multiple posts to rails for save an undefined number of points.

Thank you to all.

Answer (score 1):

A really good tutorial on this can be found here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

It gives good techniques for handling an undetermined number of nested attributes

Comment: I have decided to use another approach. Thank you.

Comment: Marco, would you be kind enough to share what approach you've decided to follow??